# my navbar dropdown menu is not working in django project using bootstrap4

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

Building my first Django app from a tutorial, following the instructions pretty much verbatim but my navbar dropdown menu is not working & im unable to logout or change password.

Here is my base.html file i don't know html i copy this code from tutorial & maybe I'm  messing anything please take a look & help me to solve the problem, Thank You :)

```
<!-- templates/base.html -->
```

```
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
     initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81i\
    uXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">


    <title>{% block title %}Bk - Newspaper App {% endblock title %}</title>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Bk-Styles-007</a>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'article_new' %}">+ New</a></li>
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu"
                       data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                       aria-expanded="false">
                        {{ user.username }}
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
                        aria-labelledby="userMenu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"
                        href="{% url 'password_change' %}">Change password</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">
                        Log Out</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        {% else %}

            <form class="form-inline ml-auto">

                <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                Log In</a>
                <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">
                    Sign up</a>

            </form>

        {% endif %}

    </div>

    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAKl8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ/6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

**I update  to

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
```

> but still facing same problem.

.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce your problem in its entirety, but your `li` tag in line 20 (right after `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`) is missing a class from bootstrap called `dropdown`.

So in line 20 instead of

```
<li class="nav-item">
```

Should be

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
```

If that doesn't fully solve your problem, I suggest you edit your question and add the entire code (maybe you didn't import the Bootstrap Javascript? I'm not able to know with just this code snippet).

**EDIT**

Ok, since you posted your entire code I found what is wrong with it. As suspected, the javascript code was not being imported correctly, because **your SHA hashes from the scripts tag, parameter integrity are invalid.** This is a really important feature to guarantee that you're importing the right code from a CDN (not some malicious code). Since you're following a tutorial, you probably got a hash that's no longer valid.

I recommend getting the [most up to date version](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/) of Bootstrap 4 from their site (at the time of writing, it's 4.5). Replace your imports by these and it should work. To save you some time, I've copied the new info:

CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

JS:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you really need the 4.1.3 version of Bootstrap, you can find it in [this site](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/legacy/bootstrap/), but my guess is that you don't. Prefer the most up to date version.

Comment: Thanks  Daniel for helping me but It can't solve my problem I'm updating my question & I hope you to take 1 more look to Help me.  Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @MBilalAsgher now that you posted the full code, I've found the error. As suspected, the javascript code was not being imported correctly

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Thank you very very much it really helps me  a lot I just copy & paste your suggested code & it solves my problem in seconds. Again thanks buddy.

Comment: @MBilalAsgher I'm glad it helped =)